# php contact form, thank you page

Tags: php

Below is my php contact form:

Page the user inputs information:

```
<div style="padding-left: 50px">
<p class="arial"><strong></strong><br /><br /></p>
<form action="freecontact2formprocess.php" method="post"> 
<table class="freecontact2form" border="0" width="400px">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td colspan="2"><span style="font-size: x-small;"> </span> <font color=#E42217 >Please ensure all card details are correct.</font>
  <br /><br /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td valign="top"><table width="400px" class="freecontact2form">
    <tr>
      <td colspan="2"><br />
        <br />
        <div class="freecontact2formmessage"> </div></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
  <td valign="top"><label for="subject_type" >Subject Type:<span class="required_star"> * </span></label></td>
  <td valign="top"><select name="subject_type" id="subject_type">
    <option selected="selected" value ="Maths">Maths</option>
    <option value ="English">English</option>
    <option value ="Biology">Biology</option>
    <option value ="Chemistry">Chemistry</option>
    <option value ="Physics">Physics</option>
    <option value ="History">History</option>
  </select></td>
</tr>


<tr>
  <td style="text-align:center" colspan="2"><br /><br /> <input src="../../images/submit1.png" name="submit" type="image"> <br /><br /> <!--      If you want to remove this author link,     please purchase an unbranded version from: http://www.freecontact2form.com/unbranded_form.php       Or upgrade to the professional version at: http://www.freecontact2form.com/professional.php     --> <br /><br /></td>
</tr>
  </table></td>
  <td valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
</tr>


</tbody>
</table>
</form> <br />
<p> </p>
<p> </p>
```

This is freecontact2formprocess.php:

```
if(isset($_POST['subject_type'])) {

    include 'freecontact2formsettings.php';

function died($error) {
    echo "Sorry, but there were error(s) found with the form you submitted. ";
    echo "These errors appear below.<br /><br />";
    echo $error."<br /><br />";
    echo "Please go back and fix these errors.<br /><br />";
    die();
}

if(!isset($_POST['subject_type']) ||
    !isset($_POST['testvariablealwaysset']) ||


    ) {
    died('Sorry, there appears to be a problem with your form submission.');        
}

$subjecttype_from = $_POST['subject_type']; // required









$headers = 'From: '.$email_from."\r\n".
'Reply-To: '.$email_from."\r\n" .
'X-Mailer: PHP/' . phpversion();
mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_message, $headers);
header("Location: $thankyou");
?>
<script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>
<?php
}
die();
?>
```

this is freecontact2formsettings:

```
<?php

$email_to = "myemailaddress@emailaddress.com"; // your email address
$email_subject = "Subject type"; // email subject line


if ($subjecttype_from="Maths")
{
$thankyou = "http://www.google.com";
}
else
{
$thankyou = "http://www.yahoo.com"; // thank you page
}

// if you update the question on the form -
// you need to update the questions answer below
$antispam_answer = "25";

?>
```

On the freecontact2formsetting file, i have set a condition that if the user selects Maths from the drop down menu, the thank you page is set to google.com, if however anything else is selected it goes to yahoo.com. Currently all redirects are going to google.com regardless, how do i make sure when the user selects anything but maths, it goes to yahoo.com?

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning rather than evaluating, change your `if` statement to:

`if ($subjecttype_from == "Maths")`

You could also write it like this:

```
$thankyou = ($subjecttype_from == "Maths") ? 'http://www.google.com' : 'http://www.yahoo.com';
```

From looking at your code, `$subjecttype_from` isn't defined when your `if` statement is evaluated. Assign the variable before you include the file which makes the comparison, eg:

```
$subjecttype_from = $_POST['subject_type']; // required
include 'freecontact2formsettings.php';
```

Comment: redirect does not work with this, it simply gets stuck on reecontact2formprocess.php

Comment: is `$subjecttype_from` defined when you compare it? By the looks of it you assign it after the file is included..

Comment: thats it, its included before i assign it. thanks. is it possible to use an if else condition here then: <script>location.replace('<?php echo $thankyou;?>')</script>, by using $thankyou1 if maths is selected else $thankyou2 ?

Comment: What would be the values of `$thankyou1` and `$thankyou2`? There's no point creating two separate variables

Comment: $thankyou1 = "http://www.google.com"; $thankyou2 = "http://www.yahoo.com"; with an if else statement after location.replace